# IMPORTXHTML giving could not fetch url error from nasdaq in Sheets

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I'm trying to get data from the row open interest to appear in my Google Sheets. I have tried both IMPORTHTML and IMPORTXML, but I keep getting the could not fetch url error. Here is the current code I am working with.

```
=IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/funds-and-etfs/spy/option-chain/call-put-options/spy---201224c00370000"),"//tr[text()='Open Interest']/td")
```

When I inspected the table every row has the same class, so I can't select by class, same goes for header. So I'm not sure how to access the line once the URL can be fetched

I have tried http: and https:, that's not it.

Comment: https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/funds-and-etfs/spy/option-chain/call-put-options/spy---201224c00370000

Comment: UrlFetchApp times out as well, I think this may be an issue with IP blacklisting so save from spam. In this case there's not really anything you can do.